# ASP.NET MVC - How do I access a specific property from a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am learning how to apply ViewModels to ASP.NET MVC. I'm unsure how to be able to access "specific" properties of the ViewModel from within the View. I've got a ViewModel containing a whole bunch of properties like this:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductDescription> ProductDescriptions { get; set; }
}
```

Now, previously when I had a "listing" type page I could simply do this in the View (as can be seen, I'm accessing two different properties here, `Products` and `ProductDescriptions`):

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Products.ElementAt(i).Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Products.ElementAt(i).ProductID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ProductDescriptions.ElementAt(i).Description)
        </td>
}
```

However I'm now totally stuck on implementing a "details" like page where I only need to access specific records For example:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Products.ProductID)
```

Does not compile because ""Model.Products" does not contain a definition for "ProductID"". However, the Products model does have a ProductID or else the "listing" page code would not compile.

How do I fix this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ViewModels or MVC, this is basic C#.  Your previous code used Lists (or some other collection type that allowed index access) while your new code uses IEnumerable, which does not allow random access (you can only "enumerate" it from beginning to end.)

Answer (score 0):

[Erik Funkenbusch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61164/erik-funkenbusch) answered your problem, but an easy way to iterate a Collection is like this:

```
@foreach (var product in Model.Products)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => product.ProductID)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```